# Mobile view (/one/one.app) differs from native Salesforce1 view

Tags: salesforce1-app, app

I wondering why the mobile view in the desktop browser (/one/one.app) differs from the native view on my Android smartphone (Nexus 5 with Salesforce1 App).

For example, the view page(no Visualforce!) of a custom object record looks fine at the mobile view in the desktop browser, but at the Android phone it is rendered like it is rendered on my normal Desktop.

It seems that this only appears if the record is opened via a Visualforce page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you "open via Visualforce page" that record exactly?

If it's `/{!record id here}` or some kind of action method that returns `PageReference` (most likely with redirect?) - yep, it'll end up becoming a standard ("desktop") view of the record.

You should be detecting the S1 and using it's own navigation methods instead (like `sforce.one.navigateToSObject('{!record id here}','detail')`.

Consult the [S1 documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_dev_best_practices.htm) and welcome to the world of pain ;) You might decide to have 2 separate VF pages rather than one that tries to work in both wo

I found these presentations quite useful:

- http://www.slideshare.net/keirb/salesforce1-vf
- http://www.slideee.com/slide/using-visualforce-in-salesforce1
- http://foobarforce.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/df13chatterpublisheractionsandsalesforce1.pdf